# how do i cast a .net single to equivalent byte array that can be stored on the heap?

Tags: .net

how do i cast a .net single to equivalent byte array that can be stored on the heap?

this is to be used as a glfloat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwsaf3w.aspx